# Pagination and filtering on frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, apollo-client, mern

I got this code for getting page and products limit in backend:

```
getProductsPagination: async (_, { page }) => {
  const skip = (page - 1) * 12;
  const limit = 12;
  const total = await Product.countDocuments();

  let query = Product.find({});

  query = query.skip(skip).limit(limit);
  const pages = Math.ceil(total / limit);

  const result = await query;
  return { products: result, numOfPages: pages };
},
```

I am filtering products from the frontend and everythings work great but the thing is only in page 3 I have products with the color pink, so If I am at page 1 and trying to filter the color pink It will not display these products. I will have to jump to page 3 for that. This is even possible to make to work only in frontend?

front end code:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS_PAGINATION, {
    variables: { page },
  });

  const products = data?.getProductsPagination?.products;
  const numOfPages = data?.getProductsPagination?.numOfPages;

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredProducts(products);
    const applySort = (filteredList) => {
      return sort.length <= 0
        ? filteredList
        : sort.includes('price-highest')
        ? filteredList?.slice().sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
        : sort.includes('top-rated')
        ? filteredList?.slice().sort((a, b) => b.rates - a.rates)
        : filteredList?.slice().sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
    };
    const sizePredicate = (product) => {
      return size.length === 0 || product.size.includes(Number(...size));
    };
    const brandPredicate = (product) => {
      return brand.length === 0 || product.brand.includes(...brand);
    };
    const pricePredicate = (product) => {
      return (
        price.length === 0 ||
        (product.price > price[0][0] && product.price < price[0][1])
      );
    };

    const colorPredicate = (product) => {
      return color.length === 0 || product.color.includes(...color);
    };

    setFilteredProducts((filteredList) =>
      applySort(
        filteredList
          ?.filter(sizePredicate)
          ?.filter(brandPredicate)
          ?.filter(pricePredicate)
          ?.filter(colorPredicate)
      )
    );
  }, [products, sort, price, brand, size, test, color, page]);
```

Comment: It's possible to make only in frontend, but I think recalling the API with required filters would be better approach.

Comment: Like making a query in backend with filters value ?

Comment: Yes, structure your schema so that it can accommodate the filters

Comment: Thank you will try, but then each time user choose a filter option ( size, color, etc...) it will make a new request to the server, is it ok ?

Comment: If you were at the point of having to think about micro-optimizations, you would know.

Comment: If your app is so much reactive then yes. See I'm suggesting the simpler approach. If you want to handle the filtering logic in frontend then you may come up with many cases, so making API request is simpler.

Comment: Making a new request to the server to get the filtered items is the way. It's the simplest, cheapest, and most standard way to do this. Find a filter button on the internet somewhere and open the network tab to see what's going on.

Comment: You'll also have to add an index for `color` and anything else that's going in your `find` query.